# Does the mongodb php driver require php5-dev?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I'm trying to install mongodb in a PHP environment. MongoDB itself is installed fine, I've run `pecl install mongo`, and added `extension=mongo.so` to php.ini; but my Laravel application complains that it can't find the class MongoClient. Checking phpinfo() reveals no mention of Mongo, suggesting that it isn't aware of the driver.

I noticed that all the instructions for installing mongo on Ubuntu mention `apt-get install php5-dev`. Is that a requirement for the mongodb php driver? At the moment the server is built with Chef and installs php with `apache2::mod_php5`. If `php5-dev` is required, can it be installed as an apache module?

Comment: It is a requirement by PECL to compile the driver, you just need the package, nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you should as stated by docs here http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/
Also if its unable to find mongo drivers ,Try debugging , check logs if it says something like mongo.so file is missing.

Don't forget to restart php and apache after saving php.ini